Is there a 1-1-correspondence between joint characteristic functions and random vectors?
On the internet, I keep seeing that two random variables $X,Y$ are independent if and only if
$$\varphi_{X,Y}(s,t) = \varphi_X(s)\varphi_Y(t),$$
where $\varphi$ represents the characteristic function defined by $\varphi_{Z_1, \ldots, Z_k}(t_1,\ldots, t_k) = \mathbb{E}(e^{i(t_1Z_1+\ldots+t_kZ_k)})$ for a random vector $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_k)$. I was wondering if the same is true for more than two random variables, but cannot really find good sources on joint characteristic functions and their properties (on the internet).
So: Are random variables $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ mutually independent if and only if their joint characteristic function factors into their individual ones? The 'only if' part is clear to me. If the answer is yes, can anyone point me to a source which discusses properly?

The andwer is "yes", and one of the way to see it, is to notice that you can write
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1\in A_1,...,X_n\in A_n)
$$
usung the characteristic function and the inversion formula, and in case the joint ch.f. is a product of the individual ones, this will be equal to the product
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1\in A_1)...\mathbb{P}(X_n\in A_n).
$$
